# How to copy (duplicate) dictionary without the values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to copy it (duplicate it) but just keep the keys and somehow empty values. For example, let's say I have this:

```
dict1 = {'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'C'}
```

I would like to copy it to dict2 but without the values (which aren't valid for dict 2) like this:

```
dict1 = {'a':'', 'b':'', 'c':''}
```

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(dict1, '')` ? You can do this with a simple-loop as well, but I guess you didn't try anything at all.

Comment: `dict2 = {i: '' for i in dict1}`

Comment: Apparently, I wasn't clear enough. i wonder whether there's a way to copy it WITHOUT using ifs and fors etc.

Is this why my q gets -1s? Gee, ppl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dict1 = {'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'C'}

dict2 = dict.fromkeys(dict1, '')
```

Or

```
dict2 = {k:'' for k in dict1}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. :)